# Flutter Azure AD Auth: How to display the user email and name retrieved during login to another screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I have successfully retrieved the user email and username from Azure AD Auth. But I want to display this in Text widget in home screen. How can I send the username from the Signin class to home screen and display the name?

Signin

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  MsalMobile msal;
  bool isSignedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MsalMobile.create('assets/auth_config.json', authority).then((client) {
      setState(() {
        msal = client;
      });
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    });
  }

  /// Updates the signed in state
  refreshSignedInStatus() {
    msal.getSignedIn().then((loggedIn) {
      print('refreshing');
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;

        if(isSignedIn) {
          // Your navigation code
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NavScreen()));
        }
      });
    });
  }

  /// Signs a user in
  handleSignIn() async {
    await msal.signIn(null, [SCOPE]).then((result) {
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        final ex = exception as Exception;
        print('exception occurred');
        print(ex.toString());
      }
    }
    );
  }

  logMsalMobileError(MsalMobileException exception) {
    print('${exception.errorCode}: ${exception.message}');
    if (exception.innerException != null) {
      print(
          'inner exception = ${exception.innerException.errorCode}: ${exception.innerException.message}');
    }
  }

  /// Signs a user out.
  handleSignOut() async {
    try {
      print('signing out');
      await msal.signOut();
      print('signout done');
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    } on MsalMobileException catch (exception) {
      logMsalMobileError(exception);
    }
  }

  /// Gets the current and prior accounts.
  handleGetAccount() async {
    await msal.getAccount().then((result) {
      if (result.currentAccount != null) {
        return result.currentAccount.username;
      } else {
        print('no account found');
      }
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        print('exception occurred');
      }
    });
  }
```

home screen

```
class _HomeScreenDesktop extends StatelessWidget {
  final SignIn handleGetAccount;
  final TrackingScrollController scrollController;
  const _HomeScreenDesktop({Key key, this.scrollController, this.handleGetAccount}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: MoreOptionsList(currentUser: currentUser),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Container(
          height: 1000.0,
            width: 600.0,
            child: ListView(
              controller: scrollController,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Show Retrieved username from azure account",
                            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          "assets/notification.png",
                          width: 24,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                GridDashboardwe()
              ],
            )),
        const Spacer(),
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xff392850) ,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am using this method on the signin screen to get the account details

```
/// Gets the current and prior accounts.
  handleGetAccount() async {
    await msal.getAccount().then((result) {
      if (result.currentAccount != null) {
        return result.currentAccount.username;
      } else {
        print('no account found');
      }
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        print('exception occurred');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user object via parameters from the `SignIn` class to the `_HomeScreenDesktop` widget. Also, you should make the home screen widget public instead of making it private. Using an underscore before the class name means it is private ie, use `HomeScreenDesktop` instead of `_HomeScreenDesktop`.

Also please specify the return type of methods which will be really very helpful.

Updated `handleGetAccount` method:

```
Future<dynamic> handleGetAccount() async { // <-- Replace dynamic with type of currentAccount
    await msal.getAccount().then((result) {
      if (result.currentAccount != null) {
        return result.currentAccount;
      } else {
        print('no account found');
        return null;
      }
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        print('exception occurred');
        return null;
      }
    });
```

Call method `handleGetAccount` to get current signed-in user & then you can pass this user object to the `HomeScreenWidget`, which will look something like this:

```
/// Updates the signed in state
  refreshSignedInStatus() {
    msal.getSignedIn().then((loggedIn) {
      print('refreshing');
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;

        if(isSignedIn) {

          dynamic currentAccount = await handleGetAccount();

          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NavScreen(
                    currentAccount: currentAccount, // <--- Passing required named parameter "currentAccount" in NavScreen widget. 
                  ),
              ),
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

The `NavScreen` widget will also be updated by creating a constructor as follows:

```
NavScreen({
  @required this.currentAccount, // Required currentUser parameter 
});

final dynamic currentAccount; // Replace dynamic with the type of currentUser
```

From `NavScreen`, I guess you must be navigating to `HomeScreenDesktop` somehow, but while doing this, you need to pass this `currentAccount` object to the `HomeScreenDesktop` & create the same constructor & parameter as in `NavScreen` widget (something like this):

```
HomeScreenDesktop({
  @required this.currentAccount, // Required currentUser parameter 
});

final dynamic currentAccount; // Replace dynamic with the type of currentUser
```

You will also have to pass the `currentAccount` object while navigating.
It will look something like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomeScreenDesktop(
      currentAccount: currentAccount,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi, when I try to access the currentUser on the home screen like `Text(
                   "Hi, ${currentUser} ",` it show Hi null, not getting the username, anyhting ma doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check. Also, in order to print username, you need to write `Text('Hi, ${currentAccount?.username})`

Comment: Hi master @Ravi  setting await on `setstate(){}` throws error, this line `setState(() {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;

        if(isSignedIn) {

          dynamic currentAccount = await handleGetAccount();` I changed it to   `dynamic data = await handleGetAccount();
      setState(()  {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;
        dynamic currentAccount = data;`

Comment: but still getting null, username is not being passed all the way

Comment: Can you share with me your repository so that I can review your code.

Comment: In `nav_screen.dart`, you have a list of widgets `_screens`. In that list, the first item is `Home()` & you also haven't passed  `widget.currentAccount` in this `Home` widget. This is leading to the user object being `null`.

Comment: You will have to pass `widget.currentAccount` in the `Home` widget. You can do this in the `initState` method.

Comment: you've confused me, I pass this  `widget.currentAccount` I pass it inside  like this `Home(widget.currentAccount)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You will also have to create the `dynamic currentAccount` in `Home.dart` & use it, constructor, as well (as shown in the answer above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224406/discussion-between-blackbird-and-ravi-singh-lodhi).