# Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Converting objects to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to send multiple object that I want to send through dio when i try this i get

> Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Converting
> object to an encodable object failed.Instance of 'DateTime'

I hav also tried converting the object to Json but i still get other errors

My Model

```
BasicInfoModel basicInfoModelFromJson(String str) => BasicInfoModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String basicInfoModelToJson(BasicInfoModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class BasicInfoModel {
  BasicInfoModel({
    this.id,
    this.monitorName,
    this.monitorPhoneno,
    this.fieldleadEmpno,
    this.fieldleadName,
    this.fieldleadPhone,
    this.fieldteamId,
    this.ea,
    this.district,
    this.region,
    this.date,
    this.timeStarted,
    this.timeEnded,
  });

  String id;
  String monitorName;
  String monitorPhoneno;
  String fieldleadEmpno;
  String fieldleadName;
  String fieldleadPhone;
  String fieldteamId;
  String ea;
  String district;
  String region;
  DateTime date;
  String timeStarted;
  String timeEnded;

  factory BasicInfoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BasicInfoModel(
    id: json["id"],
    monitorName: json["monitorName"],
    monitorPhoneno: json["monitorPhoneno"],
    fieldleadEmpno: json["fieldleadEmpno"],
    fieldleadName: json["fieldleadName"],
    fieldleadPhone: json["fieldleadPhone"],
    fieldteamId: json["fieldteamId"],
    ea: json["ea"],
    district: json["district"],
    region: json["region"],
    date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
    timeStarted: json["timeStarted"],
    timeEnded: json["timeEnded"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "monitorName": monitorName,
    "monitorPhoneno": monitorPhoneno,
    "fieldleadEmpno": fieldleadEmpno,
    "fieldleadName": fieldleadName,
    "fieldleadPhone": fieldleadPhone,
    "fieldteamId": fieldteamId,
    "ea": ea,
    "district": district,
    "region": region,
    "date": date.toIso8601String(),
    "timeStarted": timeStarted,
    "timeEnded": timeEnded,
  };
}
```

Extracting the json items

```
 final String id = uuid;
    final String monitorName = responses[0]['fields'][0]['value'];
    final String monitorPhoneno = responses[0]['fields'][1]['value'];
    final String fieldleadEmpno = responses[0]['fields'][2]['value'];
    final String fieldleadName = responses[0]['fields'][3]['value'];
    final String fieldleadPhone = responses[0]['fields'][4]['value'];
    final String fieldteamId = responses[0]['fields'][5]['value'];
    final String ea = responses[0]['fields'][6]['value'];
    final String district = responses[0]['fields'][7]['value'];
    final String region = responses[0]['fields'][8]['value'];
    final DateTime date = (responses[0]['fields'][11]['value'] is DateTime)
        ? responses[0]['fields'][11]['value']
        : responses[0]['fields'][11]['value'];
    final String timeStarted = responses[0]['fields'][9]['value'];
    final String timeEnded = responses[0]['fields'][10]['value'];
```

the json string I am Extracting

```
[{type: Input, label: Monitor Name, required: true, value: re}, {type: Numeric, label: Monitor Phone No(s), required: true, value: 087}, {type: Numeric, label: Field Team ID*, required: true, value: yt}, {type: Input, label: Field Team Lead Name, required: true, value: yh}, {type: Numeric, label: Field Team Phone No, required: true, value: 89}, {type: Numeric, label: Field Team Employee No, required: true, value: 89}, {type: Input, label: EA*, required: true, value: yh}, {type: Input, label: District*, required: true, value: gy}, {type: Input, label: Region, required: true, value: g}, {type: Input, label: Time started, required: true, value: g}, {type: Input, label: Time ended, required: true, value: b}, {type: DatePicker, label: Date, required: true, value:  2020-11-14 18:32:06.176338}]
```

Comment: What is the type of `timeStarted` & `timeEnded`? Are they objects of `DateTime`?

Comment: no they are not @RaviSinghLodhi

Comment: `String basicInfoModelToJson(BasicInfoModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());` Convert this function to a block function: `String basicInfoModelToJson(BasicInfoModel data) { String json = data.toJson(); print(json); try {return json.encode(data.toJson());} catch(e) {print(e.toString());}}` Also try to debug to see exactly which parameter is causing this issue.

Comment: Hi @RaviSinghLodhi help me with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956925/show-circular-progress-dialog-in-login-screen-in-flutter-how-to-implement-progr)

Answer (score 0):

How does the `json["date"]` looks like? if its null or the value cannot be parsed correctly it will throw a FormatException

try checking null first:

```
date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
```

Also check the format of json["date"], maybe its in millisencods since Epoch

Comment: Hi @EdwynZN this is the json it is not empy `{type: DatePicker, label: Date, required: true, value: 2020-11-13 08:06:18.99}` it has milliseconds

Comment: I don't fully understand, it is a map with a key named 'value' and inside a String of a date, where is the key 'date' ?

Comment: i have shared the whole json string

Comment: I don't see the relation between the response, the BasicInfoModel model and the extracted values, in the date you're asking if the response is of type DateTime, return it's value, otherwise return...its value? But it's obvious that the value won't be interpreted as a DateTime for the second option

Comment: A String, run it as final date = responses[0]['fields'][11]['value']; and check its type