# Firebase sign in with email and password for flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter and i'm trying to make firebase sign in using email and password!

everything works fine within the console but at the app it doesn't take me to the home page with correct credentials!

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/firebase/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:my_project/firebase/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:my_project/routes.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_project/theme.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      catchError: (_, __) {},
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Medical app',
        theme: theme(),
        initialRoute: Wrapper.routeName,
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**wrapper.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/firebase/models/my_user.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screens/splash/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/wrapper";
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<MyUser?>(context);
    print(user);

    if (user == null) {
      return SplashScreen();
    } else {
      return HomeScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

**sign_in_form.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/components/custom_icon.dart';
import 'package:my_project/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:my_project/firebase/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screens/forgot_password/forgot_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_project/screens/login_success/login_success_screen.dart';
import '../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';

class SignForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  _SignFormState createState() => _SignFormState();
}

class _SignFormState extends State<SignForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool? remember = false;

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: remember,
                activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    remember = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Text("Remember me"),
              Spacer(),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context, ForgotPasswordScreen.routeName),
                child: Text(
                  "Forgot Password",
                  style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          //FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continue",
            press: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // _formKey.currentState!.save();
                setState(() => loading = true);
                
                //KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
                //Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginSuccessScreen.routeName);
                dynamic result =
                    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                if (result == null) {
                  setState(() => error = 'Verify your credentials');
                  loading = false;
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue!,
      /* onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removeError(error: kShortPassError);
        }
        return null;
      }, */
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() => password = val);
      },
      validator: (val) => val!.length < 6 ? 'Enter a 6+ chars password' : null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        hintText: "Enter your password",
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
          gapPadding: 2,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
        ),
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue!,
      /* onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      }, */
      validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() => email = val);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
          gapPadding: 2,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
        ),
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**auth.dart:**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_project/firebase/models/my_user.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user object based on firebase user
  MyUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user return value (null if logged out / user obj if logged in)
  Stream<MyUser?> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User? user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user!));
  }

  //Sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  //Sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone verify my code please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is about redirecting, you dont update the app after successful login, which causes nothing on UI. Please check this answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64763115/13780308